# VisualStateManager: How to stop execution of a state A when a state B is active?

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, visualstatemanager

I have successfully managed to increase the scale of an image inside a button as soon as the mouse is hovered over the button.

Now if I was going to use the same concept for a ToggleButton the situation would be slightly more challenging.

When the toggleButton is in 'checked' State, I don't wish the mouseover state to fire its scaling animation, but the color animations should still be fired.

How could I possibly achieve this?

Many Thanks,

Comment: Hi, do you have your Color & Scale animations precluded into one visual state?

Comment: Got it, a possible solution - you could create MouseOverToggled and MouseOverUntoggled states and call your GoToState in code behind (you'll know if IsToggled == true when IsMouseOver gets changed, won't you?) You are going to lose declarativeness of your code though.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, a pity I would loose the declarativeness. At least its a solution. Let me try and see how it goes...